# Adding z-value to the triangulation output from the TIN interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tin, z-value

For a project I'm working on I need to do a triangulation over points (csv) or lines (dxf). When running the TIN interpolation from the processing toolbox I save the triangulation as a temp file.

This polygon output has no z-value in its geometry.

[image: screenshot db-manager]

With drape, I can get the z-value from the raster-output from the TIN interpolation, but not all points are on the raster so there are lines that have the default value.

[image: raster-triangulation]

Is there a way to fix this, or add the z-value to the geometry from the input source?

Comment: Hello, I didn't understand in wich source you have z-value : is it your points ? In the second img we see line partly outside of your region with raster heigth data. Can you get height data in a larger region ?

Comment: Hello, The z value is in the points or lines that are used as input for the tin-interpolation. There are 2 outputs, a raster file and a triangulation polygon file. the raster has z-values, but the polygons don't. With drape i wanted to get the z from the raster, but as shown on the last picture of my post there are some points in the polygons that are outside of the raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have points with z values and also lines that have z value (based on the points as vertices). You want lines with z values but with more vertices more points with z data.

First solution : the algorithm densifygeometries in the toolbox on your line layer source that have Z-value. It would make new vertices on each line and interpolate linearly the z-value. If you are using TIN with non-linear interpolation then it would not produce the result you want.

Other solution : you can add fake points in a larger area with the same value of the nearest point with data (manually or with algorithm). This would permit to produce a raster larger that would have value for all your line.

One way to do it with QGIS toolbox :

0. Add z value in the field : use fiedl calculator to create a field `z_value` for all your source points (the formula should be `z ($geometry)`).
1. Use tool minimum bounding geometry with your point layer as source and select convex hull as type of geometry produced. It will define a polygon around your point layer
2. Use buffer to enlarge this polygon (define the value that will enlarge 25 % at least)
3. Use tool : extract vertices
4. Use tool : join by nearest. Your vertices as entry layer and your source points as layer to join.

[image: result of your process]

4bis. On the layer produced use the tool `Set z value` with the field `z`

[image]

5. Merge your two layers.
6. Use TIN tool based on the new layer.

Normally it should be fine then : )

Comment: Your first solution isn't going to work for my problem,The polygons must be made up out of 3 vertices. When I add more vertices to the polygons, the 'end software' doesn't recognize it as a dtm. 

As for you second solution. Can you give some pointers on which algorithms might do the trick?

Comment: I did add the process to do it with qgis. If you have small dataset do it manually is a good option also.

Comment: Does-it work for your problem. You can mark as solution if it does and if it does not i could adapt it.

Comment: Hello. I just tried it. All the buffer functions I've tried only have xy dimensions. So when I use that in this process the interpolated z value will be lower than it actually is.

Comment: Hello, I have add step 0 and 4 bis to make this work... i forget to mention it.

Comment: The `$z` isn't recognized as a function in the field calculator. But with vector - add geometry it can be added to the table. The other steps are perfect.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, I corrected it in the answer.